# Webpack 4 config not showing source maps files

Tags: webpack, source-maps, webpack-4

I have configuration webpack like:

```
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: '[name]',
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

module.exports = (env, options) => {
    console.log(`env: ${env} mode: ${options.mode}`);
    return {
        entry: {
            'css/index.css': [
                entryDir + '/scss/index.scss',
            ],
        },
        output: {
            path: buildDir,
            // publicPath: 'css/',
            filename: '[name]',
        },
        watch: (options.mode == 'development') ? true : false,
        devtool: (options.mode == 'development') ? "source-map" : false,
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    loader: extractSass.extract({
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'css-loader', options: {
                                    sourceMap: true,
                                    url: false
                                }
                            },
                            'postcss-loader',
                            {
                                loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
                                    sourceMap: true,
                                    url: false
                                }
                            }],
                        fallback: 'style-loader'
                    }),
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['assets/dist/css']),
            extractSass
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpackConf",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "v4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.8.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

My config works but my source maps always pints to index.scss file and not to actual file. Index is for me only @import file of my partials.
I try options from doc https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool but none of them seems to work. Is there any additional option I should use or update package to make it work ?

Comment: I resolve this changing order of loaders for scss

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue and then played with other option and below thing working fine for me

devtool: (options.mode == 'development') ? "eval" : false